# Crystal Reports - Using Subreports as Columns

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, multiple-columns, crystal-reports-2010

I am having a small problem with formatting on a Crystal Report that I am hoping that you may be able to help me with.

Essentially, I have a Crystal Report that consists of three sub-reports. Each sub-report contains the same 3 sections, but use different data sources. Because of the different data sources, the sections in the individual sub-reports may vary in length from one another, so my full report is rendered as such:

```
Sub Report 1  | Sub Report 2  | Sub Report 3 
Section 1     | Section 1     | Section 1
a             | a             | a
b             | b             | Section 2
c             | c             | a
Section 2     | d             | b
a             | Section 2     | c
b             | a             | Section 3
c             | b             | a
d             | Section 3     | b
Section 3     | a                       
a
```

Essentially, what I want to do is have all sections line up, regardless of the amount of data that may be contained in the individual sections:

```
Sub Report 1  | Sub Report 2  | Sub Report 3 
Section 1     | Section 1     | Section 1
a             | a             | a
b             | b             |
c             | c             |
              | d             |
Section 2     | Section 2     | Section 2
a             | a             | a
b             | b             | b
c             |               | c
d             |               |
Section 3     | Section 3     | Section 3
a             | a             | a
              |               | b
```

Please note, I am using the Crystal Reports plugin for Visual Studio 2010. I do not have access to the full Crystal Reports.

Comment: is is possible to break each subreport into 3 subreports? so that each subreport section turns out in a subreport itself. so, you would create 3 sections in the main report. The first one would have subreport1_section1, subreport2_section1, subreport3_section1. Then, the second section would contain subreport1_section2, subreport2_section2, subreport3_section2. So on...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, heringer. While what you suggest would work, in theory, it comes with the price of performance degradation because, instead of the main report running 3 sub-reports, it would now be running 9 sub-reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your sub reports must be linked to a common field in order to line up correctly.  Something like DATE or TIME, COLOR, PRICE.  What ever would be the same DATA in each of your data sources.  Your main report should report at least that field.
  Right click on the sub report to manage individual sub report links.

In Crystal Reports 10 exporting with multiple sub reports.
All data from the main report is forced left unless there is data from the sub in front of it.
If all sub reports are placed to the right of all info being reported in your main report, and everything is lined up correctly... your columns and rows should export correctly to a

- - TAB separated file.
    From there, import your file to excel using the "text to column wizard".

I am not having success exporting direct to an excel worksheet. BUT, it works famously by exporting to a TAB Separated Text File and then importing to excel via the TEXT to COLUMN wizard.

Comment: Hi Stalek, all three sub-reports are linked using three different input parameters (StartDate and EndDate which create a date range for which information is populated, and ItemType which specifies the item the report is generated for). The three sub-reports generate counts based off of the parameters, one of which is an overall count, the other two are sub-set counts. Therefore, there is no data returned in the sub-reports which would be the same through-out all three reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place the subreport in the details section then go to section experts, select details and check "Format with multiple columns".  Then set the number of columns to 3 and try how the report will run. This will work just in case you can make the subreport to use the same datasource.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Lan. Unfortunately, your solution did not work for me. The individual sections of the sub-reports still do not line up with each other. Additionally, with the sub-reports in the Details section (they were previously in the page header), the data being returned decides to replicate itself, causing me to return 30+ pages instead of 2.

I think my solution is inevitablly going to come from the sql that generates the data for these reports, by forcing it to return the same number of rows for all three sub-reports (instead of null values where data may not exist in one).